# Can't remove duplicate packages because of dependencies

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

Due to an aborted yum update, I'm stuck with duplicate package dependencies.  I'm trying to use the command "**rpm -e --justdb $package**" to remove one of the duplicates, but both packages have dependencies (See below).  I could see a solution where I remove all the dependencies and reinstall them, but this could turn out to be a rabbit hole. Or worse, I could break something by removing a package that I shouldn't.

I also tried to upgrade (both yum and rpm) to the latest version of the package hoping that the dependencies would move to the new version, but I just get a "Failed dependencies" error.

```
# Two different versions of systemd-libs are installed
$ sudo rpm -e --justdb --test systemd-libs-219-19.el7_2.13.x86_64
error: Failed dependencies:
        libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) cups-1:1.6.3-22.el7.x86_64
        libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) is needed by (installed) cups-1:1.6.3-22.el7.x86_64
        systemd-libs = 219-19.el7_2.13 is needed by (installed) libgudev1-219-19.el7_2.13.x86_64

$ sudo rpm -e --justdb --test systemd-libs-208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
error: Failed dependencies:
        systemd-libs = 208-20.el7_1.6 is needed by (installed) systemd-208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
```

Is it possible to resolve this or am I screwed?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

`# yum-complete-transaction`

Or, if that command returns that there's no unfinished transactions...

`# package-cleanup --cleandupes`

And then re-run `yum update`.

Comment: `yum-complete-transaction`  gives `No unfinished transactions left.`   `package-cleanup --cleandupes` gives `--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem`

Answer (score 0):

You should just finish that yum transaction. Run:

```
# yum-complete-transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the --nodeps option on the rpm command line which disables dependancy testing thus allowing you to complete the erasure of a specific rpm package.

Comment: I see this will allow for the removal of the duplicate package, but what will it do to the orphaned dependency?